# How to determine which domain registrars (e.g., GoDaddy, Register.com) support which top level domains (TLDs)?

Tags: dns, tld

If someone wants a .LY TLD (top level domain) or .IO TLD, how do I determine which domain registrar (e.g., GoDaddy, Register.com) supports the purchasing of this TLD?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you are looking for a registrar for a niche domain the best way could be you visit the Registry's web site.  These may list authorised registrars.  The problem with going to non authorised registrars is that they will in turn have to go via a authorised registrar and that will only put up the price you pay.

- The list of .IO registrars can be found here: http://www.nic.io/registrars.html
- The list of .LY (Libya) registrars can be found here: http://www.nic.ly/lyregistrars.php

UPDATE 13/3:  The best place to find a list of registrars is the Registry's web site which is normally located at http://www.nic.[TLD].  There is a list of ICANN-Accredited Registrars which can be found at http://www.icann.org/en/registrars/accredited-list.html

Hope that this helps.

Jonathan

Comment: thanks @jonathan. is there a general approach for finding authorized registrars for other TLDs, such .TV or .ME or whatever? in other words, how did you find the links for .IO and .LY, and can this be generalized to any TLD? (i tried for .TV, and unless i did something wrong, it didn't work.)

Comment: A side caution: .Ly domains have fallen out of favor due to political instability.